# RASA NLU training data multiple entities in phrase

Tags: rasa

I'm trying to figure out how to have multiple entities generated from an from a single marked phrase.
For example:

```
what is the [forecast]{"entity":"prediction_type","value":"weather_summary","entity2":"timeframe","value2":"tomorrow"} for [New York](location)

will it [rain]{"entity":"prediction_type","value":"precipitation"} this [weekend]{"entity":"timeframe","value":"weekend"} in [New York](location)
```

From that training data, I would like 3 entities produced for every weather intent.

```
prediction_type: "weather_summary"
timeframe: "tomorrow",
location: "New York"
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of annotation is not supported